# Discord.js have role by id

Tags: discord.js

I have one bot discord and i want take a role of member by id member.

I have this :

```
    member = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (member == null) return;
    gm = message.guild.member(member)
```

But it's by mentions.

I need by nickname ID !

```
var id = message.author.id;
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `message.guild.members.cache.get()` for this.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.split(' ')
    if (args.length === 0) return
    let targetMember  = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
    if (!targetMember) return console.log('CANT find a member')
});
```

Or if you need get author.member

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message.member)
});
```